# Auto-submitting a form only on certain options

Tags: javascript, html, forms, modal-dialog

I want to create a form that would submit onchange but only on certain options. This is my code do far:

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <select name="period" id="period" class="form-control m-1" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
      <option value="" disabled hidden selected>default</option>
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

On options 1-3 I want to have it sumbitted onchange or just whenever the option is chosen but for option 4 I want to create a modal in which the user would input his data and then it would submit. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

try out the following code

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <select name="period" id="period" class="form-control m-1" onchange='onChangeFun()'>
      <option value="" disabled hidden selected>default</option>
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

javascript  below

```
function onChangeFun() {
    selected_val = document.getElementById('period').value

    if (0 < selected_val < 4) {
        // form submit function
        // this.form.submit()
    }

    if ( selected_val == 4) {
        // perform action on selection of 4 th option
    }
}
```

if any doubt comment ill happy to help

Comment: I have modified this in such way: `function onChangeFun() {
  selected_val = document.getElementById('period').value;

  if (selected_val == "1" || selected_val == "2" || selected_val == "3") {
      this.form.submit();
  } else if (selected_val == "4") {
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#period').change(function() {
          var opval = $(this).val();
          if(opval=="4"){
              $('#myModal').modal("show");
          }
      });
    });
  }
};` but it works only for option 4 after a couple of option changes

Comment: Why you modify this ?       Use  if (0 < selected_val < 4).    Is this isn't working?

Comment: Yes, with number variables it doesn't work at all.